# Get Google Calendar Events from multiple accounts

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-signin

I have a use case to get the data of google calendar events from multiple accounts that are signed in by the user and show all these data in a single calendar. Is the possible by the APIs provided by Google?

Comment: If you want them to show up in a single calendar, you'd need to create the events in that calendar, or add the other accounts as attendees to all events, so that a copy is included in their respective calendars. But if you just want them to show up in the UI, you could also share the calendars themselves with the other accounts, so that everyone can see everyone else's events. So which way would be more appropriate to you, and why do you want to show all events in a single calendar? Do you want to add those events to the calendar, or just want them to show up in the UI?

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could merge two users calendar data into a single calendar would be to read the calendar data from the first user and insert it into the single calendar one by one though the API using event.insert.

You would need to monitor these calendars all the time as  if a user changes the calendar on their original account you would need to export that over to the single calendar, you could set up push notifications though and google would inform you when there are changes to events.

Comment: Is there any way to programmatically switch between the account that the user signed in to get the calendar events?

Comment: assuming that you have a refresh token your application can load what data it needs when it needs it.